# How to return to the homepage with closing drawer?

Tags: flutter, dart

My application contains drawer widget and as default, this drawer navigate to other pages and when back button pressed it returns to the homepage with opened drawer.

How can I return to the homepage with a closed drawer?

Comment: Navigator.pop(context);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add `Navigator.of(context).pop();` before navigating to other pages. It'll close the drawer and then navigate to corresponding page and when you press back button, you'll see the drawer closed.

Answer (score 2):

I think the better way would be to use `popAndPushNamed` when you navigate to some other page on clicking the drawer. This way, your drawer will be closed first and you'll navigate to Page2 afterwards.

```
Navigator.popAndPushNamed(context, '/page2'); // use this in drawer to navigate
```